# Leaderboard from database using MongoDB/Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, leaderboard

In each document there is a level field with a Number value and a twitch_username with a String value. I want to return these values like so:

```
1. Twitch: <twitch_username> Level: <level>
2. Twitch: <twitch_username> Level: <level>
3. Twitch: <twitch_username> Level: <level>
//...
```

I tried mapping through the data, running a for loop, pushing the data into a new array, etc. but can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Currently running this query which returns the specific data I need in descending order:

```
  User.find({}).select('twitch_username level -_id').sort({level: 'desc'}).exec((err,docs) => { 
      // console.log(docs);
  });
```

The query above returns:

```
[
  { twitch_username: 'user1', level: 67 },
  { twitch_username: 'user2', level: 14 }
]
```

Which is sort of what I want but I can't individually label each value, the data is returned but I can't do anything with it.

Comment: So what is your desired output?

Comment: The first code block

Comment: Do you need to return it as a whole string like "1. Twitch: <twitch_username> Level... ?

Comment: I think returning it as a whole string makes the most sense, since each user would have their own row for the leaderboard

Comment: See my answer below. I reduced them to a single string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array reduce to reduce it to a string

```
const output = [
  { twitch_username: 'user1', level: 67 },
  { twitch_username: 'user2', level: 14 }
];
```

Then use reduce function

```
output.reduce((final, current, id) => {
    return (final + (id+1) + '. Twitch: ' + current.twitch_username + ' Level: ' + current.level + '\n');
}, '')
```